# Не удачная сборка плагина для Notepad++ NppMarkdownPanel из готовых исходников

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Исходники плагина я не изменял. Задал вопрос автору плагина https://github.com/mohzy83/NppMarkdownPanel/issues/13 но он пишет что сборка происходит удачно. Но почему тогда выходят предупреждения:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: NppMarkdownPanel, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>C:\Users\Uzzer\Downloads\NppMarkdownPanel-master\NppMarkdownPanel\MarkdownPanelController.cs(101,30,101,32): warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but never used
1>C:\Users\Uzzer\Downloads\NppMarkdownPanel-master\NppMarkdownPanel\MarkdigMarkdownGenerator.cs(36,30,36,31): warning CS0168: The variable 'e' is declared but never used
1>  NppMarkdownPanel -> C:\Users\Uzzer\Downloads\NppMarkdownPanel-master\NppMarkdownPanel\bin\Debug-x64\NppMarkdownPanel.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========[!
```

Сам Notepad++ не приманивает собранный плагин:

[image: Imgur]

Возможно у меня не установлены какие то компоненты? Вот мой файл конфигурации visual-studio-2017 :

```
    {
        "version": "1.0",
        "components": [
            "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop",
            "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop",
            "microsoft.net.componentgroup.targetingpacks.common",
            "microsoft.componentgroup.blend",
            "microsoft.visualstudio.component.entityframework",
            "microsoft.visualstudio.component.debugger.justintime",
            "microsoft.visualstudio.component.vc.tools.x86.x64",
            "microsoft.visualstudio.componentgroup.nativedesktop.winxp",
            "microsoft.visualstudio.component.vc.140",
            "microsoft.visualstudio.component.diagnostictools"
        ]
    }
```

Из этого файла можно узнать какие нужны компоненты для сборки?

```
<Project
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <UsingTask TaskName="NppPlugin.DllExport.MSBuild.DllExportTask"
             AssemblyFile="NppPlugin.DllExport.MSBuild.dll"/>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild"
          DependsOnTargets="GetFrameworkPaths"
          >
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- LibToolPath is optional - it's needed to debug C++, but you can still debug the C# code without it
            If you don't have the C++ toolchain installed this is missing, but then you can't' debug C++ anyway -->
        <LibToolPath Condition="Exists('$(DevEnvDir)\..\..\VC\bin')">$(DevEnvDir)\..\..\VC\bin</LibToolPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <DllExportTask Platform="$(Platform)"
                   PlatformTarget="$(PlatformTarget)"
                   CpuType="$(CpuType)"
                   EmitDebugSymbols="$(DebugSymbols)"
                   DllExportAttributeAssemblyName="$(DllExportAttributeAssemblyName)"
                   DllExportAttributeFullName="$(DllExportAttributeFullName)"
                   Timeout="$(DllExportTimeout)"
                   KeyContainer="$(KeyContainerName)$(AssemblyKeyContainerName)"
                   KeyFile="$(KeyOriginatorFile)"
                   ProjectDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)"
                   InputFileName="$(TargetPath)"
                   FrameworkPath="$(TargetedFrameworkDir);$(TargetFrameworkDirectory)"
                   LibToolPath="$(LibToolPath)"
                   LibToolDllPath="$(DevEnvDir)"
                   SdkPath="$(SDK40ToolsPath)"/>

    <!-- $(MSBuildProgramFiles32) points to the 32 bit program files dir.
        On 32 bit windows usually C:\Program Files\
        On 64 bit windows usually C:\Program Files (x86)\
        $(ProgramW6432) points to the 64bit Program Files (on 32 bit windows it is blank) -->
    <Copy 
        SourceFiles="$(TargetPath)" 
        DestinationFolder="C:\npp\npp32\plugins\$(ProjectName)\" 
        Condition="Exists('C:\npp\npp32\plugins\$(ProjectName)\') AND '$(Platform)'=='x86'"
        ContinueOnError="false" /> 
    <Copy 
        SourceFiles="$(TargetPath)" 
        DestinationFolder="C:\npp\npp64\plugins\$(ProjectName)\" 
        Condition="Exists('C:\npp\npp64\plugins\$(ProjectName)\') AND '$(Platform)'=='x64'"
        ContinueOnError="false" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Предупреждения только говорят, что есть неиспользуемые переменные, это ни на что не влияет. Notepad++ скорее всего каким-то своим способом проверяет совместимость. Ищите SDK для плагинов (скорее всего на сайте N++),  там должен быть описан принцип проверки совместимости.

Comment: Build: 1 succeeded - кстати говорит что сборка удачная. Предупреждения всегда говорят только о потенциальных проблемах в коде, но при наличии только предупреждений сборка происходит. Если бы были ошибки, то сборка была бы не удачная.

Comment: Как можно узнать из файлов проекта какой именно SDK нужен, и какие компоненты нужны для сборки проекта?

Comment: Где-то здесь нужная информация должна быть: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Plugin_Development

Comment: Я попробовал скомпилировать этот плагин в Visual Studio 2017. При запуске получил ту же ошибку, несмотря на то, что собрал нужную версию x86 для последней версии Notepad++. На что бы я хотел обратить внимание: DllExportTask по какой-то причине не записывает в таблицу экспорта все нужные функции в dll. В готовом бинарнике с github там экспортировано больше функций. Вот сравнение  https://i.imgur.com/qYbSBuv.png 
Причем я попробовал скомпилировать другой плагин и получил тот же результат.

Comment: Оригинальный файл по размеру больше чем файл собранный мною https://i.imgur.com/gTG10Ek.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в библиотеке Unmanaged Exports 
(PluginInfrastructure\DllExport\NppPlugin.DllExport.MSBuild.dll).

Она запускает утилиту ildasm со следующими параметрами:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\ildasm.exe" /quoteallnames /unicode /nobar /linenum "/out:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA767\NppMarkdownPanel.il" "D:\NppMarkdownPanel\NppMarkdownPanel\bin\Release\NppMarkdownPanel.dll"
```

А потом парсит и модифицирует результат.
По непонятной мне причине парсинг этого файла не работает корректно на русской версии Windows. Она не записывает в таблицу экспорта все нужные функции в dll. В готовом бинарнике с github там экспортировано больше функций.

Когда я поменял язык для не-unicode приложений в настройках Windows на английский, перезагрузил систему, и пересобрал плагин, произошло ЧУДО: все функции оказались на месте и плагин заработал! Но есть и недостаток в этом способе: некоторые старые приложения с русским интерфейсом будут отображаться с "крякозябрами".

Скриншот для Windows 8.1:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я это придумал не сам, а нашел похожую проблему [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288469/cant-create-unmanaged-dll-using-c-sharp-and-robert-gieseckes-unmanaged-exports) и решил попробовать, чем черт не шутит :)

Comment: Странное решение ...но оно работает!!!

Comment: Я даже пробовал переключать интерфейс Visual Studio 2017 с русского на английски, но это не помогло. Но каким боком настройки «Язык и региональные стандарты» влияют на сборку проекта я так и не могу понять. Спасибо вам за помощь!

Comment: Менял разные языки, и сборка происходит удачно на любом(хоть на китайском) ...но кроме русского)))